# can't initialize Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the latest Chrome version `110.0.5481.178` and the latest ChromeDriver `110.0.5481.7700`.

When initializing the chromedriver  `var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` I'm getting a TimeOut exception. `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58801/session timed out after 60 seconds.`

Until the latest chrome version, my project worked as expected, but this exception suddenly kept popping up.

I have downloaded the same version of chrome but this time from `chromium` as a standalone version on the same machine targeting the chrome to run from the "Standalone" directory and it worked!
Can anyone explain this behavior?
What can\should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: This can be tricky to solve. 1) Try killing all ChromeDriver.exe processes that are running (if using Windows). The binary name is just "chromedriver" for non-windows operating systems. 2) heck to make sure anti-virus software isn't interfering, or maybe firewall software running on your machine. 3) Make sure port 58801 doesn't already have an application listening on it.

Comment: @GregBurghardt does 58801 is the default ChromeDriver port?

Comment: I don't think the default port for ChromeDriver is the issue. Anti-virus software or firewall software might be interfering. Honestly, try out gords' answer. Sometimes you just need to do something repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who gonna tackle this issue, found that the following resolved it.
I'm not sure why the same project worked for over a year without this argument being added and now I must add it in order to communicate with the chrome browser.
Anyway, add this argument and it should solve the issue.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
```

I also found that the default `remote-debugging-port` is `4444`.
I have changed the port to `4444` in order to try reproduce the behavior but it still worked.
So I really can't say why it solved my issue like a magic.
If anyone knows why, I'll be happy if you can share it with us.

Answer (score 2):

To continue past a random exception, that happens occasionally, I start chromedriver like this

```
private IWebDriver StartBrowserChromeHeadless()
{
   var maxRetries = 3;
   var retries = 0;

   while(true)
   {
      try
      {
         return StartBrowserChromeHeadlessDriver();
      }
      catch
      {
         if (retries++ == maxRetries)
         {
            throw;
         }
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
      }
   }
}

private IWebDriver StartBrowserChromeHeadlessDriver()
{
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless=new");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadFolder);

    var chromeDownload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "behavior", "allow" },
        { "downloadPath", downloadFolder }
    };

    var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverFolder, chromeOptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSecs));
    driver.ExecuteCdpCommand("Browser.setDownloadBehavior", chromeDownload);
    return driver;
}
```